# What is the best way to implement an interface at runtime in dotnet core?

Tags: c#, dynamic, runtime, .net-core, reflection.emit

I want to do something like this:

```
    interface IMyInterface
    {
        void DoSomething();
        string SaySomeWords(IEnumerable<string> words);
    }

    public class InterfaceImplFactory
    {
        public void RegisterInterface(Type type)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public InterfaceType GetInterfaceImpl<InterfaceType>()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var factory = new InterfaceImplFactory();
            factory.RegisterInterface(typeof(IMyInterface));

            var impl = factory.GetInterfaceImpl<IMyInterface>();

            impl.DoSomething();
            impl.SaySomeWords(new List<string>() { "HelloWorld", "thanks"});

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

After i googled **How to implement an interface at runtime in c#**, most articles are old. I want to solve this problem by using **lambda**, **dynamic** but not emit.Is there a way like this to work it out?

Answer (score 4):

*Answering what you asked:*

System.Reflection.Emit is the correct way to do what you are asking. `dynamic` and lambdas are C# language features. In other words, they are compiler magic, but under the hood, they are used to produce intermediate language (IL) at compile-time. System.Reflection.Emit is the best way to produce IL at run-time.

*Now, guessing at what I think you meant to ask:*

That said, in your sample above, it looked like what you're really asking for is type-lookup. *Implementing* an interface at runtime is difficult, but resolving an implementation from an interface is not difficult.

There are half a dozen dependency injection frameworks that will do this for you. For example, if you were to use [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/), your code could look like this.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

interface IMyInterface
{
    void DoSomething();
}

class MyImplementation : IMyInterface
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // implementation here
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<IMyInterface, MyImplementation>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        IMyInterface impl = services.GetRequiredService<IMyInterface>();
        impl.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i posted another question more detailly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44993532/signature-of-the-body-and-declaration-in-a-method-implementation-do-not-match)