# Signature of the body and declaration in a method implementation do not match

Tags: c#, .net-core, cil, reflection.emit

I want to implement an interface at runtime, however when i execute

```
return Activator.CreateInstance(typeBuilder.CreateTypeInfo().AsType(), new RPCRequestProxy());
```

in ***RPCClientFactory.cs*** it throws

> `System.TypeLoadException: Signature of the body and declaration in a
>   method implementation do not match`.

I use dotnet core 1.0.4.

The entry point ***Program.cs*** :

```
namespace RPC
{
    interface IRCPClient
    {
        Task Foo([UrlParam]int b, [UrlParam]string a, [UrlParam] DateTime c);
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var factory = new RPCClientFactory();
            factory.Register<IRCPClient>();

            var cli = factory.GetClient<IRCPClient>();
            cli.Foo(1, "HelloWorld", DateTime.Now);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The ***RPCClientFactory.cs***:

```
    public class RPCClientFactory
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object> _clients = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object>();

        public void Register<ClientType>()
        {
            Register(typeof(ClientType));
        }

        public void Register(Type type)
        {
            if (!_clients.TryAdd(type, CreateImplInstance(type)))
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"bad type{type}");
        }

        public object CreateImplInstance(Type type)
        {
            var typeBuilder = CreateTypeBuilder(type);
            var methods = type.GetMethods();

            var field = CreateFiled(typeBuilder);
            CreateCotr(typeBuilder, field);
            CreateMethods(typeBuilder, methods, field);

            typeBuilder.AddInterfaceImplementation(type);

            return Activator.CreateInstance(typeBuilder.CreateTypeInfo().AsType(), new RPCRequestProxy());
        }

        private static TypeBuilder CreateTypeBuilder(Type type)
        {
            var typeSignature = "MyDynamicType";
            var an = new AssemblyName(typeSignature);
            var assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");
            TypeBuilder tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeSignature,
                    TypeAttributes.Public |
                    TypeAttributes.Class |
                    TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
                    TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
                    TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
                    TypeAttributes.AutoLayout,
                    null);

            return tb;
        }

        private static FieldInfo CreateFiled(TypeBuilder typeBuilder)
        {
            return typeBuilder.DefineField("_proxy", typeof(RPCRequestProxy), FieldAttributes.Private);
        }

        private static void CreateCotr(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, FieldInfo proxyField)
        {
            var ctorBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public
                , CallingConventions.Standard
                , new[] { typeof(RPCRequestProxy) });

            var il = ctorBuilder.GetILGenerator();

            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(object).GetConstructor(new Type[0]));
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, proxyField);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        }

        public void CreateMethods(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, MethodInfo[] methods, FieldInfo field)
        {
            foreach (var method in methods)
            {
                CreateMethod(typeBuilder, method, field);
            }
        }

        private static void CreateMethod(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, MethodInfo method, FieldInfo proxyFiled)
        {
            var paramters = method.GetParameters();

            var methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(method.Name,
                MethodAttributes.Public,
                CallingConventions.Standard,
                method.ReturnType,
                paramters.Select(x => x.GetType()).ToArray());

            var il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

            il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(Dictionary<string, object>).GetConstructor(new Type[0]));
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);

            for (var i = 0; i < paramters.Length; ++i)
            {
                var param = paramters[i];

                if (param.GetCustomAttribute<BodyParamAttribute>() != null) continue;

                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, param.Name);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, i + 1);

                if (param.ParameterType.GetTypeInfo().IsValueType)
                {
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, param.GetType());
                }

                il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(Dictionary<string, object>).GetMethod("Add"));
            }

            var proxyMethod = typeof(RPCRequestProxy)
                .GetMethods()
                .First(x => x.Name == "PostAsync" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2);

            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, proxyFiled);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "xxx.xxx.xxx");
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, proxyMethod);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(methodBuilder, method);
        }

        public ClientType GetClient<ClientType>() where ClientType : class
        {
            _clients.TryGetValue(typeof(ClientType), out object cli);
            return cli as ClientType;
        }

        public ClientType GetRequiredClient<ClientType>() where ClientType : class
        {
            var cli = GetClient<ClientType>();

            if (cli == null) throw new InvalidOperationException($"bad type{typeof(ClientType)}");

            return cli;
        }
    }
```

The ***RPCRequestProxy.cs***:

```
    public class RPCRequestProxy
    {
        public RPCRequestProxy()
        {

        }

        public async Task PostAsync(string url, IDictionary<string, object> urlParams)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("URL:"  + url);

                Console.WriteLine("QueryString:");
                foreach (var kv in urlParams)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{kv.Key}={kv.Value}");
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

After register IRCPClient, i hope it generates a class like this:

```
    class RCPClient : IRCPClient
    {
        private readonly RPCRequestProxy _proxy;

        public RCPClient(RPCRequestProxy proxy)
        {
            _proxy = proxy;
        }

        public Task Foo([UrlParam] int b, [UrlParam] string a, [UrlParam] DateTime c)
        {
            var urlParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            urlParams.Add(nameof(b), b);
            urlParams.Add(nameof(a), a);
            urlParams.Add(nameof(c), c);

            return _proxy.PostAsync("xxx.xxx.xxx", urlParams);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, i worked it out:

1: We must **DeclareLocal** before we use a local value.

2: Change `paramters.Select(x => x.GetType()).ToArray()` to `paramters.Select(x => x.ParameterType).ToArray()`

This is my final **CreateMethod** method of ***RPCClientFactory.cs***

```
        private static void CreateMethod(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, MethodInfo method, FieldInfo proxyFiled)
        {
            var paramters = method.GetParameters();

            var methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(method.Name,
                MethodAttributes.Public 
                | MethodAttributes.Virtual
                | MethodAttributes.HideBySig
                | MethodAttributes.SpecialName,
                CallingConventions.Standard,
                method.ReturnType,
                paramters.Select(x => x.ParameterType).ToArray()); // change this line

            var il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

            il.DeclareLocal(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>)); // add this line
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(Dictionary<string, object>).GetConstructor(new Type[0]));
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);

            for (short i = 0; i < paramters.Length; ++i)
            {
                var param = paramters[i];


                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, param.Name);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, (short)(i +1));

                if (param.ParameterType.GetTypeInfo().IsValueType)
                {
                    il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, param.ParameterType);
                }

                il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(Dictionary<string, object>).GetMethod("Add"));
            }

            var proxyMethod = typeof(RPCRequestProxy)
                .GetMethods()
                .First(x => x.Name == "PostAsync" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2);

            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, proxyFiled);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "xxx.xxx.xxx");
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, proxyMethod);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question! It really helped me out to program a RabbitMQ RPC Proxy!